# ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Angular

Tags: angular, error-handling

I am trying to make a responsive style of a component. Deal with windows resize. Value will giving by an expression **getRight()**.


My HTML:

```
<div [hidden]="index > 3" [style.right]="getRight()" class="chat-box card">
............
</dv>
```

In my component.ts

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-chat-box',
 templateUrl: './chat-box.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./chat-box.component.scss']})

export class ChatBoxComponent implements OnInit {

       @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
       onResize(event) {this.currentWidth = event.target.innerWidth;}
       
       currentWidth: number;
       
constructor(){}
ngOnInit() {}

getRight() {
   if(this.currentWidth <= 700 || window.innerWidth <= 700){
          if(this.currentWidth){
             return ((this.currentWidth -320)/2).toString()  + 'px';
           }
       return ((window.innerWidth -320)/2).toString() + 'px';
       }
       if(this.index==1 && window.innerWidth > 700 ){
       return '380px';
   }
return (380 +330).toString() + 'px';}  }
```

And the error messange will be:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'right: 710px'. Current value: 'right: 11px'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you should do it. That function will be called with every change detection cycle. Better is to respond to the resize, and only calculate it then. Way more performant:

```
<div [hidden]="index > 3" [style.right.px]="right" class="chat-box card"></div>
```

```
export class ChatBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  right: number;

  @Input()
  index?: number;

  @HostListener('window:resize')
  setRight() {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    
    if (width <= 700) {
      this.right = ((width - 320) / 2);
    } else if (this.index === 1 && width > 700) {
      this.right = 380;
    } else {
      this.right = 380 + 330;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setRight();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.index) {
      this.setRight();
    }
  }
}
```

<sub>I'm ignoring some weird logic you've implemented, but I suggest you also take a better look at the angular guides on angular.io</sub>

I can however suggest you to use the `OnPush` change detection strategy. This will already reduce the amount of `ExpressionHasChanged` errors drastically, makes your app more performant, and increases the logic of when change detection happens.

---

A more advanced way, would be to use the `async` pipe in combination with `rxjs`:

```
<div [hidden]="(index$ | async) > 3" [style.right.px]="right$ | async" class="chat-box card"></div>
```

```
export class ChatBoxComponent {
  @Input()
  set index(index: number) {
    this.index$.next(index || 0);
  }

  readonly index$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  readonly right$: Observable<number> = combineLatest([
    this.index$,
    fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(
      startWith<Event, void>(void 0)
    )
  ]).pipe(
    map(([index]) => this.getRight(index))
  );

  private getRight(index: number): number {
      const width = window.innerWidth;
    
      if (width <= 700) {
        return (width - 320) / 2;
      }

      if (index === 1 && width > 700) {
        return 380;
      } 
       
      return 380 + 330;
  }
}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-egxrfu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, but this change doesn't  affect to right value when window resize.

Comment: @ChanchenPork I've updated my answer with a stackblitz, which has both above solutions implemented, and if you resize the iframe on the right, you can see that the right gets updated when that panel is smaller than 700

Comment: Wow that's work for me thank you. But If i want to increase **this.index** by number of chat-box that have open. for example i open two chat-component. So index =2.

Comment: @ChanchenPork I the index an `@Input()`?

Comment: No, the index is declare in class.

Comment: My goal, i want to give **right** based on number of chat box. For example when i open next chat-box, ts **right** will be 
**frst-chat-box.right + ((number of chat-box   -  1) * width of chat-box**. chat component is child of another component.

Comment: @ChanchenPork better would be to make it an Input() to keep the components as 'dumb' as possible. Ive updated my answer how it would work with an index as input